# Find closest controller scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to find the closest parent scope inside a `directiv`e that is a controller `scope`?

[Use case](http://plnkr.co/edit/mSeVBIP7X1mBvjEjiKVi?p=preview).

The important part is at `line 212` is the `js file`.

The template I render from the directive has `scope` expressions passed in the `directive` attribute and I need to link them to the controller `scope`.

Because the directive has an isolated scope, I link it to `scope.$parent` because in this case the parent is the controller.
But this might not always be the case, so how can I find the closest parent controller `scope`.

Can I loop trough the `scope` checking if it's a controller `scope`?

```
var template = angular.element(html);
var linkFn = $compile(template);
var child = linkFn(scope.$parent); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
$(element).append(child);
```

Comment: This is a pretty egregious approach.  I'd recommend you look into `$broadcast` and `$on` if you need to communicate data from a directive to other parts of your app

Comment: I can't have another directive listening to the $broadcast of this one

Comment: Of I can but I can't do it... Does my answer seems the best suit?

Comment: No, that is a very bad solution actually.  You should not be messing with angular's built-in objects.  In your directive, you should use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to send your data and `scope.$on` to receive it.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use jqLite/jQuery methods from within your directive to traverse DOM tree up and locate the required parent (`element.parent()`, etc). Then you can get the scope object related to this parent by calling `scope()` method on it, which you should be able to pass as an argument to your compilation function.

Comment: What if I don't know the name of the controller scope the directive is in? Does the controller scope has something particular?

Comment: the `scope()` method is defined on any jqLite element, you don't have to look for elements that define controllers only. Here's how you could access the immidiate parent scope for your directive: `link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              var parent = element.parent().scope();
              element.on("click", function(){
                parent.$apply("myVal = 'something else'")
              });` where `myVal`  is a property defined on the parent scope (in relation to your directive).

Comment: I know every element has a scope. I need to link this element to the controllers scope, not another scope. For example: If  a directive uses a isolated scope or an child scope and my directive is added inside this one. To find the controller: `element.$parent().$parent()` is needed

Comment: Please don't use jQuery to traverse the DOM. @ZenDD what is even the point of using Angular?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the cleanest approach, but you can always pass in an object to the directive's scope.

```
angular.app('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', [function() {
        var self = this;
        self.directiveConfig = {
            method1: function() { /* do something cool */ },
            method2: function() { /* do something cool */ }
        };
    }])
    .directive('myElem', [function() {
        var myElem = {
            restrict: 'AE',
            controller: function() { /* some custom controller */ },
            link: function(scope, element, attributes, ctrl) {
                /** 
                 * scope.config will now be tied to self.directiveConfig 
                 * as defined in the controller above
                 */
            },
            scope: {
                config: '='
            }
        };
    });
```

Then, assuming your controllerAs is set to `ctrl`, you could do.

```
<my-elem config="ctrl.directiveConfig"></my-elem>
```

A better solution would be to put any functions you need to use like that inside a service that can be reused.

Answer (score 2):

See there are many ways . One of the way could be , you could check for an variable that is defined on that controller scope like this

```
if(angular.isDefined(scope.$parent.variableName))
{
   // controller is defined
}
else
{
   // controller is not defined
}
```

If this is defined then it is your controller , otherwise something else. Second way would be to check parent scope of the parent  like this

```
if(angular.isDefined(scope.$parent.$parent)) {
  //controller is defined
}
else
{
  //controller is not defined
}
```

As every controller will have a parent as $rootScope or $scope of some other controller . That means if it is not a controller then this would result in undefined and will go else condition.

Answer (score 1):

requiring ngController seems to be the best solution.

```
.directive("mobilitTree", function() {
    return {
        ...
        require: "ngController",
        ...
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngCtrl) {
            ...
        }
    };
})

.controller("AppController", function($scope, ...) {
    //Only variable applied on this are public
    this.controllerOnSort = function(...) { ... };
});
```

Comment: Your question was about finding a scope not finding a controller. Maybe you want to change it accordingly.